# Is the country of origin for a beer always the same as the brewers country of origin?

Tags: breweries, specialty-beers, craft-beers

I am creating a craft beer application which will contains a lot of information about beers.

Now when modeling the data I am contemplating whether a beer itself should have a country, city and other address information, or whether this data should come from the brewery which owns the beer.

Can anyone come up with a valid reason why for example the country of origin from a beer would differ from that of the owning brewery's country of origin?

I ask this because a lot of time when you look at open source beer databases and projects you will see a country of origin when looking at a single beer but they are probably fetching it from the brewery that owns the beer.

Comment: Wouldn't [AB InBev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AB_InBev_brands) be the perfect reason for separate data? It continues to acquire companies globally, assuming control of international and local brands. I would bet many of the brands are made in multiple countries other than country of initial brew. They almost certainly have a global cadre of brewers developing product possibly brewed somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not that common, but brewers may open subsidiaries.

In 2016, [Stone Brewing Co.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Brewing_Co.) from US opened a new plant in Germany (I suspect they wanted to expand in the European market). Where would your application locate those beers? (Plant was recently sold to Scottish [Brewdog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BrewDog)).

I suggest you locate beers where they are brewed.

Answer (score 2):

It's not common that the country of origin fora beer always the same for brewers country of origin.

Exploring and Expanding the business is one the most important objective for every business especially for Food and Beverages Industries. Let's take an example of well know brewery company i.e Heineken. On February 15, 1864, the Heineken is establishing and manufactured in Amsterdam. Later on, It was started the selling in other regions of Netherlands such as Zoeterwoude, Rotterdam, Etten-Leur and so on.

After the consuming and popularity of Heineken beer. It is also brewed in the United Kingdom, Ireland, Serbia, Australia, and Saint Lucia for those respective markets.

Comment: You are right. After doing some research it seems better to set this information per individual beer.

Comment: @Stephan-v Yup Absolutely Stephan.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the large multinational breweries like Budweiser or Heineken, they always have to list the country the beer was brewed, but not the country that the business originated in. Heineken is brewed in the UK and Ireland and Netherlands. If you are in the UK it should state on the bottle that it was brewed in the UK, unless they imported the bottles so it might be hard to track down. But all products, whether they be cars or soap or toys or computers must have a country they were manufactured in.

[Read this about Heineken.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heineken)